# Data model and storage for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, data-modeling

At the moment ’m building a web app using Ruby on Rails. I try to get my head around the data model and database part. To make it easy to understand I’ll use IFTTT as an analogy:

In the app, the user can add different `recipes`, for example:

- Facebook — Twitter
- Weather — Send email
- You name it...

Of course every recipe has its own fields and options. So the user can choose multiple recipes from the library and set options to every recipe. The library of recipes is defined in code.

I have a few questions regarding this setup and would be happy if I could get some directions:

1. Is it smart to serialize the options of a recipe into a single database field? Every recipe has different fields and I don‘t want a database table for every recipe type.
2. Or is it better to create a ‘key-value’ table with all the options of all the recipes?
3. How to handle validation? Can [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) come in handy?
4. Is a NoSQL database a good fit for these kinds of applications?

Are there best practices for these kinds of applications/data models? Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Rens

Comment: Check out postgres hstore. I think noSQL is not a good idea to start a rails app with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if SO is the best place for really general questions like this but I'll take a swing

1 && 2) Personally I'd give the `recipe` table an `action_taken` field, probably as a string, and fields for all the available, resulting actions as booleans. Then the only thing you really need to be careful of is making sure the `action_taken` field remains uniform

3) ActiveRecord has a pretty fleshed out [validation suite](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) built in. You can validate based on presence, uniqueness, inclusion in a set of elements, etc. You can also extra validations on the database if you feel like being extra safe

4) I would use PostgreSQL, seems to be the community standard so probably the easiest to get support with if you need it

Hope this helps